# How is it possible to draw unconnected nodes with networkx?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

When using networkx I only now that there are several possibilities of plotting graphs with edges and nodes.

Is it possible only to plot a lot of nodes, without connections between them? The points all have x- and y-coordinates. The points are saved in a pandas dataframe with only 3 columns: ID, X, Y

```
g = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df1, source='x', target='y')
```

I tried something like this but I don´t want to have edges only points.

This is a part of the dataframe:

```
               id   x         y
0              550  1005.600  1539.400
1              551  1006.600  1549.400
2              705  1029.997  2140.001
3              706  1030.997  2141.001
4              478   180.000  1354.370
5              479   190.000  1354.370
..             ...       ...       ...
500            237  1135.000  2615.000
501            238  1145.000  2615.000
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example of input DataFrame?

Comment: Now, what would be the expected graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw nodes and edges separately. Use the following to only draw the nodes:

```
nodes=nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G)
```

If you want to pass the specific position of the nodes you may want to create the pos out of the x and y values. (At that point I would rather not use networkx...)

See the [docs...](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#draw-networkx-nodes)

Comment: How is it possible to to define the nodes according to their coordinates?

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using?